# Join 2 MySQL Tables to list all posts and find users followed by a particular user (Logged INN User)

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables in my project.

**POSTS Table**

```
p_id     p_user_id      p_title     p_description
.................................................
1        1              Post 1      lorem ipsum * 1
2        1              Post 2      lorem ipsum * 2
3        2              Post 3      lorem ipsum * 3
4        3              Post 4      lorem ipsum * 4
```

**FOLLOWERS Table**

```
f_id     f_following_users_id    f_followed_users_id     f_date
...................................................................
1        2                       1                       2018-01-25
2        2                       3                       2018-01-25
3        3                       2                       2018-01-25
```

Now I want to get list of all users depending on Logged in users id. The logged in users id is taken from $_SESSION['user_id'].

The result I want is like as follows.

**First Case:** if logged in users user_id is 1, ie, $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1, or following_users_id in 2nd table is 1, The result should be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 1
        [p_user_id] => 1
        [p_title] => Post 1
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 1
        [f_id] => 
        [f_following_users_id] => 
        [f_followed_users_id] => 
        [f_date] =>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 2
        [p_user_id] => 1
        [p_title] => Post 2
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 2
        [f_id] => 
        [f_following_users_id] => 
        [f_followed_users_id] => 
        [f_date] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 3
        [p_user_id] => 2
        [p_title] => Post 3
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 3
        [f_id] => 
        [f_following_users_id] => 
        [f_followed_users_id] => 
        [f_date] => 
    )
    
)
```

**last four fields of array should be blank as user with user_id haven't followed anyone**

**Second Case:** if logged in users user_id is 2, ie, $_SESSION['user_id'] = 2, or following_users_id in 2nd table is 2, The result should be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 1
        [p_user_id] => 1
        [p_title] => Post 1
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 1
        [f_id] => 1
        [f_following_users_id] => 2 
        [f_followed_users_id] => 1
        [f_date] => 2018-01-25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 2
        [p_user_id] => 1
        [p_title] => Post 2
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 2
        [f_id] => 1
        [f_following_users_id] => 2 
        [f_followed_users_id] => 1
        [f_date] => 2018-01-25
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 3
        [p_user_id] => 2
        [p_title] => Post 3
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 3
        [f_id] => 
        [f_following_users_id] => 
        [f_followed_users_id] => 
        [f_date] => 
    )

)
```

*First four fields of first 2 array should be filled with first row of followers table as user with user id has followed user with user_id 1. And 4 rows of 3rd post should be blank as user with user_id 2 haven't followed user with user_id 2***

**Third Case:** if logged in users user_id is 3, ie, $_SESSION['user_id'] = 3, or following_users_id in 2nd table is 3, The result should be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 1
        [p_user_id] => 1
        [p_title] => Post 1
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 1
        [f_id] => 
        [f_following_users_id] => 
        [f_followed_users_id] => 
        [f_date] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 2
        [p_user_id] => 1
        [p_title] => Post 2
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 2
        [f_id] => 
        [f_following_users_id] =>  
        [f_followed_users_id] => 
        [f_date] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 3
        [p_user_id] => 2
        [p_title] => Post 3
        [p_description] => lorem ipsum * 3
        [f_id] => 3
        [f_following_users_id] => 3
        [f_followed_users_id] => 2
        [f_date] => 2018-01-25
    )

)
```

First 2 arrays 4 last column should be blank as User_id 3 haven't followed those posts users. But third arrays last four column should be filled as user_id 3 has followed user_id 2.

I have searched for all solution but in vain. Maybe I couldn't find right post how to do this even on Stack Overflow.

The MySQL query I tried is:

```
SELECT * FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN followers AS f ON p.p_user_id=f.f_followed_users_id WHERE f.f_followed_users_id = p_user_id AND f.f_following_users_id = 1 ORDER BY p.p_id
```

But I don't get the results I wanted. I tried with left join right join outer and inner joins. But no success. Can I join these 2 tables like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you could try something like looping instead of joining tables as ur followers table will have only one row which satisfy your conditions.

so why dont you try like this:

1) get all posts from your database.
2) foreach post you retrieved, get data from followers table with ur conditions.
3) create a new array.
4) if step 2 return result, merge followers table data to new array along with post.
5) else merge post itself to new array.

and once you finish for each loop, try to print it and check data using,

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
exit;
```

try this and let me know if you need any further help

Comment: at last a response. lemme try this and will let you know. got the concept. will ask you if i have any further doubts. thanks for your time :)

Comment: that worked man! anyway i feel like this will be slow when my database grows. anyway thanks for your suggestion man.